# Solve the trigonometry equation in rational form.

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{\tan^2x\sin^2x}{1-\sin^2{x} \cos2x}+\frac{\cot^2x\cos^2x}{1-\cos^2x\cos2x}+\frac{2\sin^2x}{\tan^2x+\cot^2x}=\frac32$$

What I thought:

$\frac{\tan^{2}x\sin^{2}x}{1-\sin^{2}x\cos 2x}+\frac{\cot^{2}x\cos^{2}x}{1-\cos^{2}x\cos 2x}+\frac{2\sin^{2}x}{\tan^{2}x+\cot^{2}x}-\frac32=0$.

Transform each fraction into $\tan x$,
then you can factor out $(\tan x-1)^{2}(\tan x+1)^{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $\cos^2x = t$ then you have:

- $\sin ^2x = 1-t$
- $\tan^2 x = {1-t\over t}$
- $\cot ^2x = {t\over 1-t}$ and
- $\cos 2x = 2t-1$